# MAUI: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider?

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

**Goal**:
I have an app I migrated from Xamarin.Android to .NET MAUI Android. I want to be able to run it (on device/emulator).

**Problem**: I am getting this error:

> .Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider
> androidx.support.v4.content.FileProvider:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "androidx.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList

**What I've done**: I looked up parts of this error, I see some people mention that the android.support provider needed to be changed to androidx.support, so I did that in the AndroidManifest.xml file, it now looks like:

```
<provider android:name="androidx.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

I'm not even sure if AndroidX is needed for MAUI. I thought that was just for Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

I see I needed to use core.content instead of support:

```
<provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
```

Although I'm still not sure if I should be using androidx at all for MAUI?